# Jquery fullCalendar filter events and can't render the filtered events

Tags: jquery-plugins

This is my first time asking a question here.  I am using the jQuery plugin fullCalendar and for the most part I have it working great with exception of one problem.  I have added a filter to the calendar events where when a user clicks on a checkbox, I want to reload the calendar and query a database to get the filtered results.  I am able to do this without problems but, if I am on a month that is not the current month, the calendar will always go back to the current month with the filtered results.  The user would then have to click on the prev/next buttons to get back the that they were on.

One solution that seems to work up to a point is this:

```
function reloadCalendar(formInputs, height, view, startView, endView) {
    var source1 = {
        url: 'ajax.php?c=careerDevCalendar&a=getEvents',
        data: {
            filter: formInputs
        }
    };
    var s = Math.round(startView.getTime() / 1000);
    var e = Math.round(endView.getTime() / 1000);
    var source = 'ajax.php?c=careerDevCalendar&a=getEvents&startF='+s+'&endF='+e+'&'+formInputs;
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents');
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('removeEventSource', source1);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', source);
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
}
```

I am able to get the filtered results in a JSON array and the calendar stays on the month that I happen to be on, but it won't render the events in the calendar.  Does anybody have any ideas on what I can do to filter events without having the calendar go back to the current month?

Thanks in advance